# terraform reports name argument not defined for resource_group

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Aim: To create an Azure resource group using variables and enforce naming constraints.

Terraform Azure resource group module definition is as below.

cat **locals.tf**

```
locals {
  tags = {
    "Environment" = var.environment_name
    "Department"  = var.department
    "Managed By"  = "Terraform Open Source"
  }
}
```

cat **main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = regex("^[-\\w\\._\\(\\)]+$",substr("rg-${local.environment_name}-${local.application_name}-${var.location}", 90))
  location = var.location
  tags = local. Tags
}output "resource_group_id" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.id
  description = "Resource Group id"
}
```

cat outputs.tf

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
  description = "The name of the resource group"
}

output "resource_group_location" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location
  description = "The location of the resource group"
}
```

cat **providers.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.4.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.55.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

cat **variables.tf**

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the resource group"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "Location of the resource group"
}

variable "environment_name" {
  type        = string
  description = <<EOT
    (Optional)  The name of the environment where the resources will be deployed.

    Options:
      - dev
      - uat
      - test
      - prod

    Default: dev
  EOT

  default = "dev"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("dev|uat|test|prod"), var.environment)
    error_message = "Err: environment name is not valid."
  }
}
variable "department" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the department"
}
variable "cost_centre" {
  type        = string
  description = "Cost Centre for the Resource or Resource Group"

}
variable "application_name" {
  type = string
  description = "Name of the application"
  
}
```

Now, I have created an example like the one below.

cat **main.tf**

```
module "rg" {
  source           = "./.."
  location         = "australiaeast"
  environment_name = "Dev"
  department       = "Data Services"
  cost_centre      = "ABC101"
  application_name = "demo"
}
```

cat **provider.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.4.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.55.0"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run **terraform plan**, I get an error like the one below.

**Error**:

```
│ Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 1, in module "rg":
│    1: module "rg" {
│ 
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code, it clearly defines `name` variable **without a default** value:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Name of the resource group"
}
```

Since there is no default value given, you have to **explicitly provide** `name` when you instantiate your `rg` module. If you don't want to do this, you have to define a default `name`, e.g.:

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  default     = "some-default-rg-name"
  description = "Name of the resource group"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Marcin! My bad, my mistake. Thank you for your prompt guidance.